# Constructor function giving error

Tags: javascript, html, function, constructor

I am trying to present an example of constructor function. I hope I am doing all correctly, still getting error. Can someone help me out?

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body> 
<script>

var alhpa = function(name, age){
this.name = name;
this.age = age; 
}

var obj1 = new alpha("Peter", 29);
var obj2 = new alpha("Jenny", 17);
var obj3 = new alpha("Mark", 34);

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
console.log(obj3);

</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: its a typo.. your variable is `alpha` not `alhpa`

Comment: @priya_singh the typo _was_ OP's problem

Comment: @SurajRao Ya. That's why i corrected it. instead of posting ans.

Comment: @priya_singh ok.. but correct way is to close as typo.. editing will change the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a **spelling mistake** `alhpa` != `alpha`

**Demo**

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body> 
<script>

var alpha = function(name, age){
this.name = name;
this.age = age; 
}

var obj1 = new alpha("Peter", 29);
var obj2 = new alpha("Jenny", 17);
var obj3 = new alpha("Mark", 34);

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
console.log(obj3);

</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks Like you have a spelling mistake.

**This should be alpha not alhpa**

```
var alpha = function(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age; 
}

var obj1 = new alpha("Peter", 29);
var obj2 = new alpha("Jenny", 17);
var obj3 = new alpha("Mark", 34);

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
console.log(obj3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename the `alhpa` to `alpha`. It's is a careless mistake.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body> 
<script>

var alpha= function(name, age){
this.name = name;
this.age = age; 
}

var obj1 = new alpha("Peter", 29);
var obj2 = new alpha("Jenny", 17);
var obj3 = new alpha("Mark", 34);

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
console.log(obj3);

</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: heh.. you compounded it :p .. _Rename the alpha to alpha_

Comment: again my typo :p :p thanks @SurajRao